# Nonincreasing sequence converges to?

Tags: calculus

Consider function $f(x)$ without bounded below condition. For a nonincreasing sequence $f(x_n)$, is the following statement TRUE?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) =\inf f(x)\geq -\infty$$

Comment: Map $\mathbb{R}$ into $(-1,1)$, say via $x\mapsto x/(1+|x|)$, in a way that preserves order. Then $\pm\infty$ are maped to $\pm 1$, and all limits and supremums and such are preserved. This way you translate all your questions to the case when $f(x_n)\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: I have made changes to the original question.

Comment: If $f(x)=\sin (x)$ (or $x\sin(x)$, if you want something truly unbounded) and $x_n=2n\pi$, what would happen?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. My confusion was from this: for a bounded below, nonincreasing sequence $x_n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\inf x_n$. For a bounded below, nonincreasing function sequence $f(x_n)$, what conditions do we need to make  $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\inf f(x)$?